# Vs code insert mode

Tags: visual-studio-code, insert

При нажатии cmd+c включается режим будто нажата клавиша insert, помогает только несколько нажатий c c c c, потом опять спокойно редактировать код можно, как убрать такой режим и спокойно копировать дальше?